# The Application not running in old simulators

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

My Application is not running one the old simulators With Blackberry JRE 5,6. The project runs fine on the new simulators with JRE 7 (model 9900, 9810, 9860). The memory size of the application is more than ~6MB.

I tried Cleaning the application in all such ways. In lower simulators the COD file also gets deployed in the simulator, but it doesn't shown in the downloads folder.

What might be the problem.

Comment: Which sdk did you use for app building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "~6MB".  That is pretty close to the maximum app size on older versions of BBOS.  You might need to factor your app into multiple cods, to keep the size of the cod groups smaller.

Comment: ya you are right, with your reference i reduced the image size. which makes runs on the old  devices.

Answer (score 1):

Which BlackBerry JRE did you develop your app in? Please note that BlackBerry apps are not backward compatible, i.e. an app developed in JRE 7.0 will not work below OS 7 as not all APIs used in JRE 7 will be available in the older operating systems. BlackBerry apps are forward compatible and for an app to function on OS 5, 6 and 7, you should develop the application in JRE 5.